# How to concatenate double curly brackets with variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django

I can't seem to figure this one out. I've got a Python/Django template which renders my variables using {{ variable }} and I'm trying to use Javascript on the HTML page to manipulate the variable when the user clicks a button.

The problem I'm seeing is that Javascript seems to treat {{ differently, so that when it renders as HTML, it doesn't convert the variable (ie. it shows "+ id + " instead of 5 from the code below:

```
function changeDate()
  id = 5;
  html = "{{ variable[" + id + "] }}";
  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = html;
```

I've tried escaping them like this: "{{" and that seems to work (ie. it converts 'id' to 5) but then Python doesn't interpret the string as a variable and it just displays the string on the page as {{ variable[5] }} rather than the real value of that variable.

My *guess* is that this happens because Javascript is converting the DIV to the new text *after* the page is already rendered, so Python never has the chance to convert the variable when it first renders the page.

So I think there are two possible solutions:

1. Figure out a way to render the variable properly while leaving the {{ and }} in the string

or

1. Figure out how to get Python to interpret the string version of {{ variable[5] }} before it's ever displayed through Javascript.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your server-side code doesn't know about JS variables. Any JS code and html is just included in the response as is. All of the server-side code runs before the browser gets the response.

Comment: so...you have a JavaScript function, and you want it to render some HTML using Django templates? I think you are misunderstanding the nature of the client-server relationship...

Comment: @nnnnnn Your comment rules out solution #2 (getting Python to render the variable) but not #1 - why can't Javascript render a variable if there are curly brackets? Otherwise you reiterated what I already said in my question.

Comment: @nneonneo Try to offer a more helpful comment. The javascript function is being used to *manipulate* a variable that is being passed to the page using Python. Note that this works fine if I just use "5" in the string rather than passing a variable id = 5

Comment: You didn't understand the comment...Python is running on a server, which generates a page and sends HTML (and JS/CSS) down the pipe to a client, which renders the page and executes JS in the browser. Any modifications the client makes cannot be seen by the server unless the client explicitly sends it back (e.g. with AJAX).

Comment: @nneonneo Thanks for the follow up, I understand what you're saying. However if I get a Python error if use this in the javascript: 'var html1 = "{{ insights[6][" + id + "] }}"; so clearly it's possible to render the variable this way. Here's the error I get: 'TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str' 'File "admin_html.generated.py", line 287, in _execute _tmp = insights[6][" + id + "]'

Comment: No, it's not possible. You're getting an error because the template engine sees `{{ insights[6][" + id + "] }}`, which is literally asking for the key `" + id + "` in `insights[6]`, hence the error. The template engine cannot understand what `id` is because it's JavaScript.

Comment: @jgentes: nneonneo is exactly right. What is happening in that case is that Python is trying to fill that value in your *javascript* code- *not* the html that your javascript code than generates. (You'll get the same error even if you never use the `var html1` variable).

Comment: We could discuss that in chat if it's not clear (well, once there are enough comments to generate that "continue conversation in chat" link)

Comment: If I comment, will there be enough to chat about it?

Comment: Not yet it seems. I feel strange abusing the functionality like this, but the "invite user to chat" feature has been shot down, and while I could create a new chatroom, it would seem redundant.

Comment: Perhaps I can see if one more comment will activate it. ETA: You have more than 20 rep so I assumed you were able to chat. Perhaps there's another reason it's not popping up. In any case, try joining the chatroom I link below.

Comment: Please try joining this room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24069/how-to-concatenate-double-curly-brackets-with-variables-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django's template rendering just do a search/replace sort of substitution:
it gets the string inside the curly braces - and use that string as  a key int he dictionary is passed to it.

It does not try to access the dictionary values as data structures - instead, it will simply take it string representations.

So,

```
data = {"variable": ["a", "b", "c"] }
```

Can be retrieved inside the dtemplate witht he name "variable" - but the rendering template should raise  a NameError if you try to access "variable[0]"  - simply because "variable[0]" is not a key on the data dictionary above.

One way to deal with it is to defer the indexing part to javascript code, on the client, and pass javascript encoded (json) strings of the objects on the data dictionary - so you would do something along:

```
import json

function changeDate()
  id = 5
  variable = ["bla", "ble", "bli", "blo", "blu", "blew"]
  html = """<script> id = {{id}};
            document.write({{variable}}[id]);
            </script>
          """
  data = {"variable": json.dumps(variable), "id": id};
```

and pass this data to be rendered with the `html`template.

Comment: Thanks @jsbueno, I ended up pulling the python variable in using var Variable = ({{ variable[5] }}).split(","); then referencing the list values from Javascript as I had hoped for in the first place. So the trick was passing the entire list to Javascript as an array, then using that. Thanks!